# redux-form-material-ui using getRenderedComponent() throws always an error

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I'm basing on [official example](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui#instance-api) from **redux-form-material-ui** repo. My code looks like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import { TextField } from 'redux-form-material-ui';

export default class FormTextField extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    const { name, withRef, focus } = nextProps;
    if (withRef && focus) {
      this.refs[name]
        .getRenderedComponent()
        .getRenderedComponent()
        .focus();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { name, label, errorText, withRef } = this.props;

    return (
      <Field
        name={name}
        component={TextField}
        hintText={label}
        floatingLabelText={label}
        errorText={errorText}
        ref={name}
        withRef={withRef}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I'm passing `focus` and `withRef` properties ONLY for first field with error. On this field I always get an error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: If you want to access getRenderedComponent(), you must specify a withRef prop to Field(…)`

I' able, to see both `ref` and `withRef` passed to `Field`. Then in component with `ref="wrappedInstance"` I can still see `withRef="true"`. It is not passed deeper.

I would appreciate any thoughts how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

1. You needn't make your `ref` a prop, as it is local to your component. You can just call it `ref="field"` if you wish. Although this is probably not your problem.
2. Also, you might as well be passing `withRef` all the time.

It sounds like you are wanting to call `focus()` when the `focus` prop changes from `false` to `true`. For that, you should be doing something like:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
  if (!this.props.focus && nextProps.focus) {
    this.refs.field
      .getRenderedComponent()
      .getRenderedComponent()
      .focus()
  }
}
```

Does that help?